# Terms of use subtraction for two grayscale Images using Opencv & Qt

Tags: c++, css, image, qt, opencv

I want to subtract two Images in gray-scale every 40ms, I capture two Images every 40ms from two cameras then set the two Images size to( height =480, width =640), after  that I convert to gray-scale.
but when I use the subtraction (absdiff) for the two Images I get "Run-time Error".
I noticed that when I display the size of the two Images I get a unmatched Results in the size of the two gray-scale Images.

```
src_gray1 cols is: =640 src_gray1 rows is: =480  src_gray1.size =0x28fd5c
src_gray2 cols is: =640  src_gray2 rows is: =480  src_gray2.size =0x28fdcc
```

in the Header I declared: 
     cv::Mat edges1 , src_gray1 , edges2 , src_gray2 , src_gray3;

> my question: whats the problem in subtraction method, is the size of
>   the gray-scale Mat is the problem?, how I can set Same properties for
>   the two images to get Over that.

I use  Qt 5.5.0,  my code here:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_pressed()
{
     timer_40_ms->start();
     timer2_40_ms->start();
     cap1.open(0);
     if( !cap1.isOpened() )
     {
         std::cout<<"Camera1 did not open";
         return;
     }
     cap2.open(1);
     if( !cap2.isOpened() )
     {
         std::cout<<"Camera2 did not open";
         return;
     }
     cap1.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,480);
     cap1.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,640);
     cap2.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,480);
     cap2.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,640);

 }
 void MainWindow::ProcessFrame()
 {
     cv::Mat frame1;
     ii++;
     ui->textEdit->setText(QString::number(ii));
     cap1 >> frame1;
     cvtColor(frame1, src_gray1, CV_BGR2GRAY);
     std::cout<<"src_gray1 cols is:"<<" ="<<src_gray1.cols<<" "<<"src_gray1  rows is:"<<" ="<<src_gray1.rows<<"  "<<"src_gray1.size ="<<src_gray1.size<<'\n';
  }
void MainWindow::ProcessFrame2()
{
    cv::Mat frame2;
    ii2++;
    cap2 >> frame2;
    cvtColor(frame2, src_gray2, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    ui->textEdit_3->setText(QString::number(ii2));
    absdiff(src_gray1,src_gray2,src_gray3);
    cv::imshow( "CAM2 Video Labeler", src_gray3 );
    std::cout<<"src_gray2 cols is:"<<" ="<<src_gray2.cols<<"  "<<"src_gray2  rows is:"<<" ="<<src_gray2.rows<<"  "<<"src_gray2.size ="<<src_gray2.size<<'\n';
}
```

Comment: What sort of a runtime error? Did you try debugging? What did you find? | BTW, you're using `Mat::size` incorrectly (Most likely printing the value of contained pointer). You should invoke the `()` operator, and if you want the number of pixels, call `.area()` on the result. i.e. `src_gray1.size().area()`.

Comment: @DanMašek terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same number of channels), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function arithm_op

Comment: @DanMašek the run time error is "this application has requested the runtime to terminate it in an unusual way". the problem appears just when I use the  subtraction  operation.

Comment: if you posted your real code and that output is printed, the runtime error does not seem to occur in either of those methods because both couts are close to the end of the methods.

Comment: @DanMašek yes you are right, I see the output of Cout when I comment the subtraction function instruction, but when I uncomment the instruction the run-time error appears

Comment: That was Micka who pointed that out. Where and in what order are `ProcessFrame` and `ProcessFrame2` called from? I guess the timers? Is there something that guarantees that `ProcessFrame2` is never the first one to be invoked? Do you initialize `src_gray1` and `src_gray2` to anything (say, all zeroes of appropriate size).

Comment: yes in fact the ProcessFrame2 is the first one to be invoked, so I put the instruction in the ProcessFrame1 and it worked,  Although I started timer 1 before timer 2 o-0, anyway thank you very much for help.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that  ProcessFrame2()  is invoked  before ProcessFrame(), thank you @dan Masek  for help:

```
     void MainWindow::on_pushButton_pressed()
   {
     timer_40_ms->start();
     timer2_40_ms->start();
     cap1.open(0);
     if( !cap1.isOpened() )
     {
         std::cout<<"Camera1 did not open";
         return;
     }
     cap2.open(1);
     if( !cap2.isOpened() )
     {
         std::cout<<"Camera2 did not open";
         return;
     }
     cap1.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,480);
     cap1.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,640);
     cap2.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,480);
     cap2.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,640);

   }
 void MainWindow::ProcessFrame()
 {
     cv::Mat frame1;
     ii++;
     ui->textEdit->setText(QString::number(ii));
    cap1 >> frame1;
    cvtColor(frame1, src_gray1, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    absdiff(src_gray1,src_gray2,src_gray3);
    cv::imshow( "CAM2 Video Labeler", src_gray3 );
    std::cout<<"src_gray1 cols is:"<<" ="<<src_gray1.cols<<" "<<"src_gray1  rows is:"<<" ="<<src_gray1.rows<<"  "<<"src_gray1.size ="<<src_gray1.size<<'\n';
  }
void MainWindow::ProcessFrame2()
{
    cv::Mat frame2;
    ii2++;
    cap2 >> frame2;
    cvtColor(frame2, src_gray2, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    ui->textEdit_3->setText(QString::number(ii2));

   std::cout<<"src_gray2 cols is:"<<" ="<<src_gray2.cols<<"  "<<"src_gray2  rows is:"<<" ="<<src_gray2.rows<<"  "<<"src_gray2.size ="<<src_gray2.size<<'\n';
   }
```